# Does movl read from stack upwards or downwards

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, memory-address

I wonder how addressing works with the stack and `movl`, does `movl (addr) %ecx` refer to the bytes located in `addr, addr+1, addr+2, addr+3` or `addr, addr-1, addr-2, addr-3`?

For example, suppose the stack looks like this:

```
1009 : 0x09
1008 : 0x08
1007 : 0x07
1006 : 0x06
1005 : 0x05
1004 : 0x04
1003 : 0x03
1002 : 0x02
1001 : 0x01
1000 : 0x00
```

Here the left number is the address and the right number is the value.
Now when we call

```
movl (1006) %ecx
```

Will `%ecx` be `0x06070809` or `0x06050403`?

(Assume we are talking about x86)

Comment: The stack pointer may grow downward as data is put on it, but accessing the stack is like any other memory access and reads forward (each byte at a higher address). Since x86 is little endian ECX would have 0x09080706 .

Comment: @MichaelPetch This should be an answer.

Comment: This isn't about stack-growth at all, it's about endianness.  There are several duplicates, but a very quick search didn't find any that are a perfect fit.